# Проблема с созданием плагина для WP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, wp-plugin

Делаю плагин для word press на visual studio code, пытаюсь найти функцию включения плагина но её попросту нету( что делать даже не предполагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может их нужно как то подключить?

Comment: Используйте phpStorm. Он "знает" все функции WordPress и плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, после автоматического обновления ошибки пропали сами по себе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]